# Dynamic disk invalid

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I try to install ubuntu in window 7 and I made wrong disk partion via ubuntu after that window cannot boot from disk . i try from other PC to diskpart but it show invalid & not able to change to online ,here

[image]

I try in AMOEI and it show failed disk

[image]

Kindly help me ,how to recover disk 2 without lost my data,thanks